# Error al implementar la librería Datatables con Angular

Tags: angular, datatables, angular6, angular-datatables

**categoria.component.html**

```html
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Someone</td>
      <td>Youknow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Iamout</td>
      <td>Ofinspiration</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Yoda</td>
      <td>Skywalker</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Patrick</td>
      <td>Dupont</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Barack</td>
      <td>Obama</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>François</td>
      <td>Holland</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Michel</td>
      <td>Popo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Chuck</td>
      <td>Norris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Simon</td>
      <td>Robin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Louis</td>
      <td>Lin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Zelda</td>
      <td>Link</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**categoria.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoriaService } from '../services/categoria.service';
import { Categoria } from '../models/categoria';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-categoria',
    templateUrl: '../views/categoria.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../styles/categoria.component.css'],
  providers: [CategoriaService]
})
export class CategoriaComponent implements OnInit {

  public id;
  public categoria: Categoria[] = [];

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _categoriaService:CategoriaService
  ){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CategoriaComponent } from './components/categoria.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CategoriaComponent,
    DataTablesModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "webapp2": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/webapp2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
            ],
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "webapp2:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "webapp2:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "webapp2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "webapp2-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "webapp2:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "webapp2:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "webapp2"
}
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>       at Object../node_modules/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.js

Comment: Y el error es... ¿?

Comment: @PabloLozano una distracción y lo publique sin colocar el error.

Comment: Prueba con `npm install angular-datatables@6.0.0`, es lo que se recomienda en el Github oficial.

Comment: @FedericoMadoery interesante, ahora cambio el error a 
***Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'DataTablesModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.***

Comment: Ya, es un error mio allí, en ***@NgModule***, coloque ***DataTablesModule*** en los ***declarations*** y va en ***imports***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el primer error que te presenta:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at
>   Object../node_modules/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.js

Lo puedes solucionar ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
npm install angular-datatables@6.0.0
```

*Fuente: Github oficial de angular-datatables.*

---

El segundo error (mostrado en los comentarios):

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'DataTablesModule' declared by the
>   module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component
>   annotation.

Esta dado por un error de importación en *AppModule*:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CategoriaComponent,
    DataTablesModule // Erroneo
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

La importación de este tipo de módulos va en el *array* de ***imports***, como se muestra a continuación:

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        ...,
        DataTablesModule // Correcto
      ],
      ....
    })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D